# How to add more jax-rs components to the application?

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy, wildfly, ear

I want to add a @Provider ContainerRequestFilter to my web project which is already defined in another project on which my current project has dependency on. So, all the providers of that project are available to this project. Both wars are packaged as ear and deployed to wildfly. But since, context-roots are different for both the web projects (or both are different web applications), the @Provider is only working for the jax-rs resources in the first project.

So, I want to manually add the provider in the following way:

```
 public MyApplication extends Application{
    Set<..> getClasses(){
       //add provider here
    }
 }
```

If we leave that method empty, all the jax-rs resources are automatically registered. But we define that method, only the classes registered in that method are registered as resource classes. So, I want to add the provider keeping all the default loading of other resources without me having to add them in this method?

How to do that? or perhaps is there a way I can add some entry in web.xml of second project to use the ContainerRequestFilter from the first project? Can I add it under filter mapping?

Comment: Are you saying that you're using a war as a library for another war? Does that even work? Why don't you just create a jar of common classes and have that as a library for both projects? Jars are automatically scanned to pick up `@Provider` classes when classpath scanning.

Comment: My second project has dependency on the first one. So all the classes of first project are available to use in this project. I'm already using many utility classes like that. Both projects are web applications but part of an ear application. So, jax-rs of the second project is not registering the provider defined in the first project. But, if we take ejbs example, @AroundInvoke interceptor which is defined in first project can be used in the second project, since we explicitly annotate the resources to use the interceptor. But for the filter I have no way.